# Ruby on Rails: strftime() in Active Admin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strftime

this is how in front-end current date gets saved in database automatically(without datepickers n stuff):

```
<% for order in @orders %>
<%= order.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M") %>
```

That works, data in database: 2013-05-03 21:32:59.847009

But the problem is that for back-end I'm using Active Admin, and I'm making form, so orders can be edited.
But the thing is I don't really understand how to apply the same strftime function there, I thought it would be something like this:

```
f.input :updated_at, :date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M")
```

But it's not correct. Getting error:

```
undefined method `strftime' for :date:Symbol
```

Does anyone know of a solution on how to correctly implement strftime in that line?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
f.input :updated_at, :value => order.updated_at.try(:strftime,'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M')
```

`try` will prevent you from getting exceptions, when date is nil.

Comment: Says: undefined method `date' for #<Order:0x4b68fa0>

Comment: Sorry for that, of course it should be `updated_at` instead of `date`. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Active Admin uses yaml files in config/locales to determine the format for dates.

If you want your default date to be something else (assuming English, so in config/locales/en.yml):

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      long: "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M"
```

Comment: Yes, but, how do I tell the program, that I want that date, to this (updated_at) variable?
f.input :updated_at, :date   - didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question:

`t.timestamps` in table migration, creates these `created_at` and `updated_at` field additionally. These fields are default `datetime` typed field. And updated automatically when a record created or updated.

But if you want to add a field of `datetime` typed, define column type as `:datetime`
like:

run `rails g migration add_time_to_table`

this command creates a migration file, edit this file like:

```
class AddTimeToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :table, :time, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :table, :time
  end
end
```

Now this `Table` model contains a `time` attribute.
So in your ActiveAdmin view you can input `time` as `datetime` format

like:

```
f.input :time
```